# How to use \underline and \emph over several words with gb4e?

Tags: formatting, linguistics, gb4e

How can I underline several words in a gloss without messing up the alignment? Here is an MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
    \ex[*]{\gll Me \underline{very bad sentence}\\
    me very bad sentence\\
    \trans `This is an unacceptable sentence'
    }
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

As can be seen, things do not line up correctly.

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide the community with a minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing in an MWE, since this question seems rather transparent to me, and I thought it might make it more obvious to the community as to what you were asking. However, if this MWE is not representative of the question you intended to ask, please feel free to rollback the edit but then *please add your own MWE*.

Answer (score 4):

The most straightforward answer is that you cannot. `\gll` and also `\glll` count the things that are passed to them in order to line them up. And they count these things before anything that gets passed to them is expanded. So, to `gb4e`'s eyes, `\underline{...}` counts as one thing.

Moreover, it's not even the case that things like `\underline{}` and `\emph{}` are macros that can be expanded. So it is not even possible to delay the macro expansion of `\gll` (or `\glll`) until `\underline` and `\emph` are expanded (since they don't expand).

So if you **really** needed this behavior, then you would need to write a new macro for `\underline` and a new macro for `\emph` that, when passed an argument like `abc abc`, expand to something like `\underline{abc} \underline{abc}` (or `\emph{abc} \emph{abc}`).

So really, the simplest answer is to just write `\underline` and `\emph` separately for each word like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
    \ex[*]{\gll Me \underline{very} \underline{bad} \underline{sentence}\\
    me very bad sentence\\
    \trans `This is an unacceptable sentence'
    }
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you **really** need the behavior that you are after, [@egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) devised a [way to split `\emph` and `\underline` while also delaying the expansion of `\gll`](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18964579#18964579). Rather than writing a new macro for `\underline` and a new macro for `\emph`, he wrote a new macro `\GLL` that causes things like `\underline` and `\emph` to be split and also causes delayed expansion of `\gll`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\makeatletter
\def\GLL#1\\#2\\{%
  \begingroup
  \let\emph\split@emph
  \let\underline\split@underline
  \protected@edef\@tempa{#1\noexpand\\#2\noexpand\\}%
  \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\gll\@tempa
}
\def\split@emph#1{\dosplit@emph#1 \dosplit@emph\dosplit@emph}
\def\dosplit@emph#1 #2{%
  \ifx#2\dosplit@emph
    \noexpand\emph{#1}%
    \expandafter\@gobbletwo
  \else
    \noexpand\emph{#1}\space
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {\dosplit@emph#2}%
}
\def\split@underline#1{\dosplit@underline#1 \dosplit@underline\dosplit@underline}
\def\dosplit@underline#1 #2{%
  \noexpand\underline{#1}\space
  \ifx#2\dosplit@underline
    \expandafter\@gobbletwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {\dosplit@underline#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex Nonsense:
\GLL This \emph{is some nonsense} with \underline{underlining of some word} \\
     Abc defgh ijk lmno pqr stuv wx yz Ops\\
\glt “This is a test.”
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If something is underlined at one line then the counterpart object have to be grouped in second line. So, the simplest answer is:

```
\begin{exe}
    \ex[*]{\gll Me \underline{very bad sentence}\\
    me {very bad sentence}\\
    \trans `This is an unacceptable sentence'
    }
\end{exe}
```

If the words can be underlined individually then I suggest to use strut for each such word:

```
\def\u#1{\underline{\vphantom y#1}}
\begin{exe}
    \ex[*]{\gll Me \u{very} \u{bad} \u{sentence}\\
    me veryyy bad sentence\\
    \trans `This is an unacceptable sentence'
    }
\end{exe}
```

If the underlined words are longer than counterparts at second line then you can underline a group of words (including spaces between them) by `\rlap`, `\underline`, `\phantom`:

```
\begin{exe}
    \ex[*]{\gll Me \rlap{\underline{\phantom{very bad sentence}}}very bad sentence\\
    me v b sent\\
    \trans `This is an unacceptable sentence'
    }
\end{exe}
```

Comment: +1 For pointing out the strut issue. And these are some neat approaches, but your first and third approaches appear to break if the underlined words on the first line are (much) shorter than their counterparts on the second line. And that is something that isn't all that uncommon in linguistics, since we often add a good bit of information about the morphemes in the gloss in the second line.

Comment: And by 'break' I just mean don't produce the desired result.